# Python - Telnetlib socket.gaierror:

Tags: python, sockets, telnetlib

I am trying to create a telnet to Teamspeak 3 Server Query through python, this is my code:

```
__author__ = 'Khailz'

import telnetlib, socket

HOST = "unlightedgaming.com"
port = 10011
timeout = 5



for i in range(len(HOST)):
    print "scanning " + HOST[i] + " ...\n"
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[i],23,3)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass

#tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)
#telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)

tn.read_until("Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface")

print tn.read_all()
```

But i seem to get the error from socket saying that it cannot get the address.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Khailz/PycharmProjects/Teamspeak-IRC/test.py
scanning 1 ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KhailzXsniper/PycharmProjects/Teamspeak-IRC/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[i],23,3)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each character in `HOST`, you are attempting to resolve that character; this is due to your use of a `for` loop in combination with indexing `HOST`. For example in the first iteration you attempt to connect to a host with an I.P. of `"1"`- that is what produces the `gaierror`.

To fix it, just don't attempt to connect to a specific index of `HOST`: get rid of `HOST[i]` and replace it with `HOST` alone in the call to `telnetlib.Telnet`:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 23, 3)
```

---

As to what you're trying to do with that loop, however, I'm baffled.

Comment: Before hand I got the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KhailzXsniper/PycharmProjects/Teamspeak-IRC/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print tn.read_all()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 384, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 575, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
socket.timeout: timed out` I wanted to ignore this error and try for a reconnection

Comment: @Khailz Right, but that is a different error. I have fixed the problem with which you have presented me- you could always ask a different question concerning the error you just commented.

Comment: From what I researched before asking, people were saying doing a loop is the best way to solve it

Comment: @Khailz They may be right, but your implementation of it causes the error, as I have explained. I strongly advise you ask a question with the `timeout` error.